# GoogleAuthException from GoogleAuthUtil.getToken() for scope oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile

Tags: android, google-api, google-oauth, google-play-services

I am trying to obtain basic user info using Android Google-play-services library. I started with the sample project that comes with the SDK : `sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\samples\auth`.
It runs fine. My account authenticates and I can retrieve my public user info.

The problem starts when I rename the project from `com.google.android.gms.auth.sample.helloauth` to `com.mydomain.myapp` - `GoogleAuthUtil.getToken()` throws `GoogleAuthException`. Naturally one would think there is a problem with credentials. However, I am not able to find one. In the developers console I have Google Play Android Developer API turned on, and under Credentials:

```
Client ID for Android application
Client ID   XXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com
Redirect URIs
urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob
http://localhost
Package name    com.mydomain.myapp
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1)  XX:YY:ZZ:70:aa:57:f4:b2:3e:9b:b3:08:16:c5:19:45:2e:18:f8:5d
Deep linking    Enabled
```

and my fingerprint is correct. (It works fine for other APIs such as Google maps). How do I debug this problem?

**EDIT:** I have the exact same problem with the newer Google+ scope (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more debugging, the issue is certainly somewhere in the google cloud console infrastructure. I created a brand new project with a new name, added Google Play Android Developer API permissions, deleted the OAuth Android credentials from the old project, created the **exact same** OAuth credentials in the new project, and everything works. Great job Google. :-(